How to us math.js with clojurescript correctly?
Using math.js with clojurescript unsuccessfully. Please comment how to access the function of math.js with clojurescript correctly.
Error lines
1. product (math/dot v1 v2)] 

2. Ainv (math/inv A)] 

Full list
(ns numerical-methods.test
  (:require ["mathjs" :as math]))

;; Function to create and print a vector
(defn a-vector []
  (let [v [1.0 2.0 3.0]]
    (println "Vector:" v)))

;; Function to compute and print the inner product of two vectors
(defn inner-product-demo []
  (println "Dot product of two vectors")
  (let [v1 [1.0 2.0]
        v2 [3.0 4.0]
        product (math/dot v1 v2)] ;; Error : shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.dot is not a function.
    (println "Inner Product:" product)))

;; Function to invert a matrix and print it
(defn invert-matrix []
  (println "Invert a matrix")
  (let [A [[1 2 3]
           [6 5 4]
           [8 7 9]]
        Ainv (math/inv A)] ;; Error : shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.inv is not a function. 
    (println "Inverse Matrix:")
    (println Ainv)))

;; Main function to run demos
(defn -main []
  (println "Chapter 1 demos")
  (a-vector)
  (inner-product-demo)
  (invert-matrix))

;; Call the main function
(-main)

Error Message when execute in REPL.
; Execution error (TypeError) at (<cljs repl>:1).
; shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.dot is not a function. (In 'shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.dot(v1,v2)', 'shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.dot' is undefined)

; Execution error (TypeError) at (<cljs repl>:1).
; shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.inv is not a function. (In 'shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.inv(A)', 'shadow.js.shim.module$mathjs.inv' is undefined)


You have to install mathjs manually with NPM or something else.
Alternatively, you can specify mathjs in a deps.cljs file at the root of your project: https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#publish-deps-cljs
There's also another thing that's wrong in your code - functions from mathjs expect JS objects and don't know how to work with CLJS objects. So you have to either create JS objects (use #js in front of [...], as in #js [1.0 2.0]; note that it's shallow - for matrices you have to use it in front of every row and in front of the matrix itself) or convert CLJS objects into JS objects (for arrays you can use into-array, for arbitrary data - clj->js).
